# Resolve $Ay=b$ with fast method

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, matrix-equations

I am looking for method that resolve equation $$Ay=b$$
I read the paper ["Wiedemann's algorithm"](http://www.math.uzh.ch/?file&key1=9252) that is one solution for fast way to find the solution instead of Gauss-Elimination.
Could you suggest to me some method to find the solution of $Ay=b$ with low complex and computation time

Comment: See, for example, Numerical Recipes book.

Answer (score 1):

There is Strassen algorithm, which works at a computational complexity of $\mathcal{O}\left(N^{\log_27} \right)$.

Then there is Coppersmith Winograd algorithm at a computational complexity of $\mathcal{O}\left(N^{2.375477} \right)$.

Some recent developments have reduced the computational complexity further to $\mathcal{O}\left(N^{2.3728639} \right)$.

However, if your matrix arises out of some application, then chances are it has some structure (either in exact arithmetic or finite arithmetic), which can be exploited to gain further mileage.

Comment: Thank Adhvaitha very much. If my matrix is not full rank matrix, Can your suggestions find the solution,(similar the belief propagation method). One weakness of Gaussian elimination is that it requires full rank matix

Comment: @user3051460 If the matrix is not full rank then the solution need to exist. To guarantee the existence of the solution, $b$ must fall in the range of $A$. If so, then there is no unique solution. Also, the computational complexity of the algorithms will depend on the rank. So it depends on whether your rank is small or large.

Comment: Thank sir. I read the  Coppersmith-Winograd method. Could you briefly explain it to me? Apply to find solution of A=[1 1 1; 1 0 1; 0 1 1], b=[1 0 1] in bit xor operator.